# Signature difference in openGlShaderSource between OpenGL ES 2 revisions

Tags: opengl-es

I've noticed that the signature of openGLShaderSource has changed:

If you look at gl2.h from http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/ (for me at rev 16803), the signature reads:

```
GL_APICALL void         GL_APIENTRY glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar* const* string, const GLint* length);
```

Now, on an older revision of that file (rev 10602), or when looking at the desktop version of that function, the signature reads:

```
GL_APICALL void         GL_APIENTRY glShaderSource (GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar** string, const GLint* length);
```

note the missing "const" for the string parameter...

Has anyone an idea how one could detect this and keep backwards compatibility? As far as I can see, there is no "revision" macro defined, that one could check to use one version or the other.

Background information: I'm trying to compile WebKit for an embedded platform that ships the new gl2.h header. And webkit has this:

```
typedef void (*glShaderSourceType) (GLuint, GLsizei, const char**, const GLint*);
```

in http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298/platform/graphics/cairo/OpenGLShims.h and thus fails to compile when it tries to assign the glShaderSource function pointer to a glShaderSourceType-variable with the new gl2.h version...

Comment: Can you not simply perform a cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by Nicol Bolas! This seems to compile:

```
void foo(const char* const*) {}
void bar(const char**) {}

typedef void (*ftype)(const char**);

int main() {
  ftype f1 = reinterpret_cast(foo);
  ftype f2 = bar;
  return 0;
}
```